# Very elementary question, $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$ if $x^2y^2+2\log y-3x+2=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

so as per title, this is embarrassingly elementary. Am writing out some answers for an undergrad economist taking a mathematical methods course. Most of the syllabus involves Simplex / Lagrangian optimisation / linear differences etc to give  some idea of level. The above question came up, differentiating implicitly we find:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{y(3-2xy^2)}{2(1+x^2y^2)}$$

If we attack this again, we basically end up with a very ungainly formula owing to the multiplicity of terms generated by the products in the numerator and denominator (I'll spare your eyes seeing this, we're not talking quartic formula, but it ain't pretty!). While this yields a correct result, find it a bit surprising that an undergrad economics exam would have something this unwieldy / ugly in it, but maybe it does. Just wondering if there's something a bit more enlightened than brute force on this, a 'trick' of some kind, I suspect there probably isn't, but just in case someone has met this kind of thing in their travels. Thanks

Comment: Your expression for dy/dx is wrong. It should be: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3y-2xy^3}{2x^2y^2+2}$

Comment: yes thanks, sorry typo was looking at the wrong bit of my piece of paper putting $y$ back in now

Answer (score 1):

Deriving the implicit expression with respect to $x$ we have

$$x^2y^2+2\log y-3x+2=0\implies 2xy^2+2x^2yy'+2\frac{y'}{y}-3=0.$$

Deriving again the equality $2xy^2+2x^2yy'+2\frac{y'}{y}-3=0$ we get

$$ 2y^2+4xyy'+4xyy'+2x^2(y')^2+2x^2yy''+2\frac{yy''-(y')^2}{y^2}=0.$$

Finally get $y''$ from the above equality.

Comment: Hi - thanks for looking at this (for which +1 :))- the above is exactly what I have. I tried two methods, differentiating $y'$, and also differentiating implicitly twice as per your solution - as mentioned the end result is obviously fairly ungainly given the form of $y'$. I guess there's no avoiding it but only posted here in case there was a 'magic' trick  someone knew, or recognised the form.

Comment: In my opinion the idea of the question is to apply two times implicit differentiation. I don't think there is a trick to deal with all possible functions. Do an economist need this? Well, probably not. But mathematical methods courses are general, that is, for a lot of different studies. If the idea is to know if the student can apply implicit differentiation an easier expression would be sufficient. But it's my personal point of view.

Comment: makes sense, yes I agree, I have no idea why they chose this function frankly. In the same question they also ask $y''$ given $y-e^{xy}=4^x$, which again has lots of terms.

Comment: At least in this case you can write $y$ explicitly. But it doesn't help very much because the expression for the derivatives becomes ugly.

Comment: yes, exactly, I think my advice to the student would be not to get too bogged down in a question like this, demonstrate the method and not spend time trying to simplify, get marks elsewhere.